# SVG foreignObject behaves as though absolutely positioned in Webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, svg

I'm working with SVG in an HTML document. For some reason in Chrome, any content in any `<foreignObject>` element appears in the top left corner of the `<svg>` element's parent element; as though the `<foreignObject>` element was absolutely positioned or something. I don't have this problem in Firefox.

What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

Here is my test case: ([the example is also on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLYzs/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG bug in Chrome?</title>
<style type="text/css">
code {
    background: #FFFAEE;
}
pre code {
    display:block;
}
.widget-body {
    background:yellow;
    position: relative; /* This is the problem! */
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>SVG bug in Chrome?</h1>
<div>
    <p>
        The elemts in the &lt;foreignObject&gt; are not positioned properly unless the <code>.widget-body</code> rule is changed to:
                <pre><code>.widget-body {
    background:yellow;
/*  position: relative; /* This is the problem! */
    position: static;
}</code></pre>
    </p>
        <h2>The Example:</h2>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1000" height="800">
    <g>
    <g transform="scale(1) translate(100, 200)" style="cursor: move;"><foreignobject pointer-events="fill" width="300" height="350">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin: 0px; height: 100%;">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(119, 68, 0); font-family: Arial,Helvetica; font-weight: normal; border-style: none;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap;">
            <div style="width:300px;height:350px;position:static;">
                <div class="widget" style="width: 300px;">
                    <div style="-moz-user-select: none;">
                        <span>My Widget Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="widget-body" style="width: 298px; height: 323px;">
                            <div style="width: 298px; height: 323px;">
                                <div style="width: 298px; height: 323px;">
                                    This position of this yellow square <br />should approximately (100, 200)
                                    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;background:red;color:white;font-weight:bold;">
                                        This red square <br />should be <br />in the bottom right corner <br />of the yellow square.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </foreignobject></g>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expect to see (which is what I see in FireFox) is this:

[image: The behavior of my example in FireFox]

What I get in Chrome (15.0.874.121 on Fedora and on an Android Tablet) is this:

[image: The behavior of my example in Chrome. The contents of the foreignObject are not in the right place.]

I have minimal control over my HTML content as I am using both a JavaScript Framework for rich apps and pre-existing widgets.

Comment: A bug in Chrome?  Can you add a simple test case to your question?

Comment: Whoa! I actually asked this question? Totally forgot! @robertc - I will try and create a test case.

Comment: @robertc - Added an example/test case.

Comment: Works fine for me. But I have `dev` version of chrome. `17.0.942.0 dev-m` what version are you use? May be this bug in your version?

Comment: @antyrat - version 15.0.874.121. Sounds like good news to me; future versions of Chrome might not have this problem! :D

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen: I have Chrome 15.0.874.121 on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS and it displays correctly.

Comment: @DanCruz - Pics or it didn't happen! :P I tried it in both Fedora and Ubuntu and got the same issue; would you mind providing a screenshot?

Comment: @antyrat - I just installed Chrome `17.0.942.0 dev` and still have the same problem. ? I'm in Fedora14... you?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - I'm using Windows 7. Maybe this is OS specific issue...

Comment: No Problems with _Chrome 15.0.874.121 m_ on Windows 7

Comment: Super weird - I have seen this in Windows as well as in Linux!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue is not specific to Chrome as I could reproduce it in Chrome 15.0.874.121 for Macintosh as well as Safari 5.1.2. (It also occurred in older versions of Firefox for Mac, such as version 3.6.8, but the behavior is correct in the current version.) [This currently outstanding Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71819) is likely to be the cause of the issue. Global coordinates are incorrectly used for elements inside the foreignObject which means when absolute positioning is used, those elements are placed relative to the main document flow rather than the foreignObject container, and thus the SVG translate is not applied to those elements.

I have not been able to locate a general solution to this issue.

For this specific example, this will fix the layout in all of the above-mentioned browsers:

```
.widget {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

[Demonstration on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XLYzs/8/)

Comment: Those issues are actually what I'm focusing on. To be honest, I hadn't even realized the red boxes were different shapes! :P My problem is that the yellow box should not have moved up and should not be flush with the left margin. As for the header, it is actually in the right place without this rule; adding this rule (much like how my `.widget-body { position: relative; }` is breaking the behavior of the yellow box) causes the header to develop the same buggy behavior.

Comment: (Having found a full solution, I've removed the example that reunites the title with the rest of the box. It slightly breaks the comment history, but leads to a clearer answer than keeping all the edits visible.)

Comment: Further revision... pretty sure this one nails it. :)

Comment: This certainly gets the desired result... but I have several widgets suffering from this problem. I'd have to keep the `<g>` element's translation synchronized with CSS properties on all of these widgets.

Comment: The problem is your incompatible use of translate(100, 200) overall and position:absolute on the red element. position:absolute takes that element and the parent element it is positioned relative to out of the normal flow and they thus do not have the translate applied to them. Is it actually necessary to position this element absolutely?

Comment: Why are they incompatible? Do you mean "according to the spec they're incompatible"? Is this webkit doing something wrong or Firefox doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, loose language on my part. I only meant "incompatible" in the context of the Webkit browser's current implementation, which as per the bug report I've linked to is acknowledged as being the wrong behavior...

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I'll be interested to hear if you managed to find a more generic solution to this issue, prior to Webkit being patched.

Comment: Indeed - but it seems doubtful. Thanks so much for finding the WebKit ticket!

Comment: Green tick - in the end I was able to catch move/re-size events and re-position things using relative position, just like you said.

Comment: ... though I had to target the `<body>` element in the `<foreignObject>` not just the `.widget`

Comment: This may just be an old answer, and new Chrome / WebKit updates (as per Chrome 65) may have changed things, but this answer doesn't seem to be working for me any longer. The jsfiddle also acts strange - when I comment out `position:relative` the text doesn't center, though it appears that - according to the html / css - it should.

Answer (score 11):

`position: fixed;` solved the issue for me.

Comment: fixed but caused a new issue: z-index

Comment: Duncan Babbage's solution still wasn't working for me, but odd enough this did work, and doesn't hoist to the corner as I had expected! However, agreed with @AiShiguang, it does cause a z-index issue in Chrome - though it remains working fine in FireFox with no z-index issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well

Comment: This fixes position, but not scale. 11 years after the first bug report...