# Insert scopedSlot into d3 svg using foreignObject

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I'm creating a chart component using d3js and Vue (v2). In some parts, I want to support custom user content using scoped slots (in this case, custom tooltips)

```html
<my-chart>
  <template slot="tooltip" slot-scope="{ data }">
    <span>{{ data }}</span>
  </template>
</my-chart>
```

But I'm struggling to render this using d3js on a vuejs component render function. I'm trying to do something like:

```
g?.append("foreignObject").html(
  this.$scopedSlots["tooltip"]({
    event,
  }),
);
```

Obviously, the `html` method isn't appropriated. I can't find anything like this online. All other examples use the component template to insert the `foreignObject` and Vue component on the SVG. Nothing using d3js

### EDIT

As `user` I refer to developers. This code is for a lib.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what the user will be doing? Are they uploading a csv file that will be used to render the visual?

Comment: I resolve my issue. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone wants to implement something like this, I manage to resolve my issue.

## Background

SVG has a concept of [`foreignObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) which allows me to inject HTML inside an SVG. The next step is, somehow, to render the Vue component to HTML.

I'm using vue2, Vuetify, and d3js v6

## Rendering the component

```
this.$scopedSlots["tooltip"]({
    event,
  }),
```

returns a `VNode[]`, so using `Vue.extend` I create a new component, instantiate it and mount it to a `div` inside the `foreignObject` like [this](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/):

```
// Call the scoped slot, which returns a vnode[]
const vnodes = this.$scopedSlots["tooltip"]({
    event,
  });
const id = "RANDOM_GENERATED_ID";
// Append a foreignObject to an g
const fo = g?.append("foreignObject");
// Append a div to the foreignObject, which will be the vue component mount point
fo?.append("xhtml:div").attr("id", id);
// Create a new component which only render our vnodes inside a div
const component = Vue.extend({
    render: (h) => {
      return h(
        "div",
        {staticClass: "foreign-object-container"}
        vnodes,
      );
    },
  });
// Create a instance of this new component
const c = new component();
// I'm using vuetify, so I inject it here
c.$vuetify = this.$vuetify;
// Mount the component. This call will render the HTML
c.$mount("#" + id);
// Get the component rect 
const bbox = c?.$el.getBoundingClientRect();

// Resize the ForeignObject to match our injected component size
return fo
    ?.attr("width", bbox?.width ?? 0)
    .attr("height", bbox?.height ?? 0);
```

This successfully renders our component inside an SVG using d3js. At least it appears inside the DOM.

## Problems

At this point, I faced 2 new problems.

### Invalid component size

After rendering the Vue component inside the `foreignObject` it reported `width` equals 0. So, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369963/1854109) I used the next styles:

```
.foreign-object-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And voilá, habemus a visible Vue component.

### Scroll, ForeignObject, and the old Webkit Bug

My use case is this: The chart is responsive, so it re-renders after every container resizes (with some debounce), but to prevent deformations I set a minimum width to every element. With some screen sizes, this provokes some overflow, which inserts a scrollbar (browser behavior).

This is exactly what I want. But I'm using some Vuetify components on my `scopedSlot` which have a `position: relative` style.

Enters, an old bug on WebKit (Google Chrome, Safari, and Edge Chromium). This is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281695/in-chrome-why-dont-svg-foreignobjects-scale-relatively-positioned-content/10353045#10353045) and [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113)

The solution in my case is simple. As I stated before, my `foreignObject` was resized to match the rendered component. So, to prevent my components to be wrongly drawn, I change my styles a little bit.

```css
.foreign-object-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

Now, my teammates can use a generic chart with scroll support and customize some pieces of it using any Vue component (at least for now )