# Justify-content behavior in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari, flexbox

I encountered a problem with `justify-content` showing different results in Chrome (Version 47) and Safari (Version 9).

In Chrome the text inside the `foreignobject` overflows to the left, but in Safari it overflows to the right side.

It's my understanding that

```
    justify-content: flex-end;
```

should align the text to the right side and overflow to the left (as it does in Chrome). I'm struggling to make Safari do the same.

https://jsfiddle.net/g27poLd0/3/

Comment: Are you using the right syntaxes and vendor prefixes? - https://jsfiddle.net/g27poLd0/5/

Comment: @Paulie_D, not sure prefixes are needed for Safari 9.

Comment: @Paulie_D, i think so, for the production sytem I use grunt-autoprefixer. Also your jsfiddle update shows the same behavior.

Comment: The problem may be the `foreignObject` element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8185845/3597276

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test in Safari (I'm on Windoze)