# SVG foreignObject doesn't display in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, safari

I'm using d3 with svg:foreignObject to create a formatted text box that appears next to a data point on hover. The below strategy works perfectly in Chrome, but the foreignObject is not visible in Safari. The Safari inspector shows the foreignObject in the DOM, in the proper location and with all the correct data. I just can't see it! What am I missing?

My code looks like this:

```
var description = svg.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('class', 'description')
  .attr('id', 'desc')
  .attr('x', x)
  .attr('y', y)
  .attr('width', width);

var descdiv = description.append('xhtml:div')
  .append('div')
  .attr('id', 'textBox');

descdiv.append('p')
  .attr('class', 'text1')
  .attr('dy', '1em')
  .html('First line');

descdiv.append('p')
  .attr('class', 'text2')
  .attr('dy', '2em')
  .html('<tspan class="text3">' + 'Second line 1st part + '</tspan><tspan class="text4">' + ', ' + 'Second line 2nd part' + '</tspan>');

descdiv.append('p')
  .attr('class', 'text1')
  .attr('dy', '3em')
  .html('Third line');
```

**EDIT** 
It turns out the issue is that foreignObject requires a height attribute in order to display in Safari (but not in Chrome, interestingly). I can set the height after the above, like so:

```
d3.select('#desc').attr('height', height);
```

But the problem now is getting the height of the text box that has no height attribute (because the height needs to vary with the length of the text). I think something like getComputedTextLength might work, but I can't quite figure it out. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can confirm, setting a width and height ensures proper display of foriegnObject on Safari

Comment: I have set a width and a height and am *not* getting it to display correctly in safari. All my checkboxes appear in the top left corner of the screen, but display fine in Chrome

Comment: Fixed it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303446/1703772

Answer (score 1):

you should set height and width property to foriegnObject.

```
var description = svg.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('class', 'description')
  .attr('id', 'desc')
  .attr('x', x)
  .attr('y', y)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', xxx);
```

Comment: Yes, if you see the edit on the original post, it works fine if you set the height. The question is how to do this without explicitly setting the height -- in the original case, the height needed to vary with the length of the text.