# Make an SVG foreignObject scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG and am adding a foreign object (HTML div) in it. I would like to make the div (or the foreign object) scrollable. However, if I set exact height to the foreign object and `overflow-y: auto` this works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari. My code is as follows:

```
<foreignObject x="400" y="0" width="260" height="554" class="foreignObject">
    <div ...></div>
</foreignObject>
```

and then I have

```
.foreignObject {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

in the CSS. I couldn't find any reason why the above would not work in Safari. Any ideas?

Another thing I tried is to set `height` and `overflow-y` to the div inside the foreignObject. However when I do that the content of the div gets zoomed and displaced. My SVG has viewBox property set and `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"` - is it because of this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Presumably a bug. You could try reporting it to the webkit bugtracker.

Comment: If the viewBox introduces a scaling, [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221528/safari-is-not-respecting-scaling-applied-to-a-foreignobject) might be the problem.

Comment: I was having the same problem. The solution is to give a height to your div, presumably the same as your foreignObject’s height (or less). Otherwise, it doesn’t scroll because the div is not limited so it expands to the size of the enclosed text.