# Is this possible to transform an SVG foreignObject on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,200,0,0.7)';
context.fillRect(0,0,100,75);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(150, 100)">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
        <canvas x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

it just works fine on Firefox as the `foreignObject` gets translated (rotated, scaled, whatever...).
But when I turn to Chrome it isn't.

Am I missing something over here?

I've also tried to follow [this example](http://www.svgopen.org/2009/papers/12-Using_Canvas_in_SVG/#d4e105) without success as I cannot retrieve my `xhtml:canvas` element. ([here is my test](https://jsfiddle.net/6a7jz8s3/1/)).

Comment: Have a look at this old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185845/svg-foreignobject-behaves-as-though-absolutely-positioned-in-webkit-browsers

Comment: Ok thanks so that means I cannot ?! Do you know if any fixes about this bug are plannified?

Comment: In that answer they suggest changing the CSS position. For instance, it works with fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/h8fva7gp/

Comment: Hum weird thanks for the update, the translate function works but my scale and rotate doesn't...any clues?